# Evaluate complex set comprehension expression

Tags: isabelle

The following expression is evaluated fine:

```
value "{fst x | x. x ∈ {(1::nat,2::nat),(2,4),(3,4)}}"
```

But for the following expression:

```
value "{fst x | x. x ∈ {(1::nat,2::nat),(2,4),(3,4)} ∧ snd x = 4}"
```

I get error:

```
Wellsortedness error:
Type nat × nat not of sort enum
No type arity nat :: enum
```

How to evaluate such an expression? Is it possible without replacing `set` by `fset` or `list` types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set comprehensions are a bit tricky to convert to code because behind that pretty syntax with the `{f x y |x y. …}`, there are (unbounded) existential quantifiers for `x` and `y`, and unbounded existentials and code generation do not mix well for obvious reasons: an unbounded existential can only be evaluated if the underlying type has finitely many values and those values can be enumerated constructively – hence the inferred `nat :: enum` constraint.

A good way around this is to make what the way to compute this a bit more explicit by using the ‘set image’ operator `` ` `` and the `Set.filter` function:

```
lemma "{fst x | x. x ∈ {(1::nat,2::nat),(2,4),(3,4)} ∧ snd x = 4} =
         fst ` Set.filter (λx. snd x = 4) {(1::nat,2::nat),(2,4),(3,4)}"
  unfolding Set.filter_def by blast

value "fst ` Set.filter (λx. snd x = 4) {(1::nat,2::nat),(2,4),(3,4)}"
```

Comment: Thnaks a lot! `Set.filter` is what I missed.